# boost python export class got wrong

Tags: python, boost

I build boost python using b2 like this:

```
.\b2 variant=debug address-model=64 link=static --debug-configuration
```

and in my home, I use user-config.jam, and change it like this:

```
using python : 3.12 
: E:/git_src/lemt_client/3rd/Python-3.12.0/PCbuild/amd64/python_d 
: E:/git_src/lemt_client/3rd/Python-3.12.0/Include 
: E:/git_src/lemt_client/3rd/Python-3.12.0/PCbuild/amd64 
: <python-debugging>on ;
```

In stage lib it has: `libboost_python312-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_83.lib`, and I linked it in vs2022.
But I use `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` to export my class, in the link stage, the error is:

```
LNK1104  "python312.lib"
```

I'm confused, it should link python312_d.lib.
Can someone tell me why it doesn't?

Comment: I tried to clean up your question, if something went wrong you can adjust it by clicking [edit].